# As3 addChild from Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I want to add a Child which I loaded into an `Array`.
I got a `Math.random` function which returns a `Number` and should trigger the `addChild`.
And later I want to splice it into an other `Array`.

```
var ground1: MovieClip = new Ground_01;
var ground2: MovieClip = new Ground_02;
var ground3: MovieClip = new Ground_03;
var groundArray: Array = new Array();
var groundMoveArray: Array = new Array();

public function loadGroundArray() {
        groundArray.push(ground1);
        groundArray.push(ground2);
        groundArray.push(ground3);
    }

public function randomGround(minNum: Number, maxNum: Number): Number {
        minNum = 0;
        maxNum = groundArray.length;
        return (Math.ceil(Math.random() * (0 + maxNum)));
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to add a Child out of the Array with the Random Function?

Comment: You should add it to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, you are almost there... you just need a tweak to your random method to actually add the clip...

```
 var ground1: MovieClip = new Ground_01();
 var ground2: MovieClip = new Ground_02();
 var ground3: MovieClip = new Ground_03();

 var groundArray: Array = new Array();
 var groundMoveArray: Array = new Array();

 public function loadGroundArray() {
    groundArray.push(ground1);
    groundArray.push(ground2);
    groundArray.push(ground3);
 }

 public function addRandomGroundToStage(): void {
     var randomGroundIndex:int = Math.round(Math.random*(groundArray.length-1));
     addChild(groundArray[randomGroundIndex]);
 }
```